# How do i use UglifyJs to 'compile' my Javascript code and not just minify it

Tags: javascript

First of all, I know javascript isnt compiled. Uglifyjs acts as a compiler to spot out possible errors...now for my question

I just downloaded/installed uglifyjs https://github.com/mishoo/UglifyJS . I want to to compile my javascript code before minifying it. I have a fle called badjs.js and here it is:

```
    var a=10  //notice no semicolon
    a = b + 3;   // b is not declared
    alert('the value of a is ' + a);
```

The first 2 lines of badjs.js should cause uglifyjs to bark at me, but it doesn't. I run this:

```
  uglifyjs badjs.js
```

All it does is just output the minified version. How do i tell uglifyjs to notify me of errors? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by **compile** the js code? Javascript is only compiled by some engines that execute it e.g., inside the browser, like V8 that is used by Google Chrome.

Comment: @fegemo Did you read the part about using UglifyJS? I know it doesn't necessarily "compile", but that's not the point...

Comment: I agree, @lan, but the term makes the question misleading for those who may not know about this.

Comment: @Ian...i tried this uglifyjs badjs.js --verbose, but got the same result..meaning no warnings about the bad code

Comment: I\m guessing by compile OP means check for syntax errors etc?

Comment: @Nathan....exactly..we all know javascript isnt compiled

Comment: So you want to jshint/jslint your code? http://www.jshint.com, http://www.jslint.com

Comment: @Stephan...I knew jslint was coming...I am currently using jslint and heres why i want to change. Jslint reports some very weird errors, I have to put all of my .js files into one file before running jslint, and then it doesnt read the entire file. Jslint says (24% of file read). The number fluctuates but nothing higher than 27%. Theres a myriad of other things but im limited as to how much i can type

Comment: Maybe the [Google Closure compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/) will do what you need? In addition to the downloadable JAR, there's a [browser-based interface](https://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home), too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know the thread is outdated but still as google returns it I have to mention now we've got a "--lint" option:

```
uglifyjs main.js -o main.min.js --lint
```

Comment: @darwin-thanks for answering. I haven't used uglify.js in awhile, but i might in the future

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't "bark" at you. Uglify follows the js specification which says that semicolons are optional at line ends. Uglify will add the semicolon for you when it compresses it:

```
> uglifyjs --version
uglify-js 2.2.3
> uglifyjs ~/Desktop/test.js -c
var a=10;a=b+3,alert("the value of a is "+a);
```